# Runtime return me "NaN" when I use objc_msgSend_fpret() method, and I can see the value on console

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

first, I use objc_msgSend_fpret() to get a property, but it can not return the value:
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZva.jpg)

then, I log the description:
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn7R4.jpg)
[description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULt0U.jpg)

May someone tell me why I cann't get cpm value, how should I do it work?

thanks!

Comment: What is the return value of cpm? `objc_msgSend_fprer()` expects a floating point return value, but the error message is telling you that it is not.

Comment: @Daniel l write a demo to test objc_msgSend_fpret() , I think I use wrong method to get a float value with using runtime, has someone tried to get float property with any methods?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, if it will work for you

```
#import <objc/message.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TestObj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) double floatValue;

@end

@implementation TestObj
@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TestObj *testObj = [TestObj new];
    testObj.floatValue = 10.00;

    double (*retFloatValue)(id obj, SEL selector) = (double(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend_fpret;
    double val = retFloatValue(testObj, @selector(floatValue));
    NSLog(@"val %f", val);
}

@end
```